# change client and handler from DatagramPacket to POJO

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, netty, datagram

I want to modify the client **handler** to use `Foo` instead of `Datagram` -- what changes are required in the **client** itself?

Surely it's not necessary to strictly keep to datagrams to send and receive with Netty?  The [Factorial example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/factorial/FactorialClientHandler.java) uses BigInteger, so, surely, it's possible to use POJO's.

Any and all attempts to create a class like:

`class FooClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Foo>` are just non-starters for me, it literally won't send or receive with a server.  (Yes, both client and server use similar handlers, generic classes with `Foo`.)  So, I'm coming at this now from working code.

What's the key distinction between the factorial handler and the the datagram handler below?  Or, is the primary distinction in how it's used in the client?

client:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.netty;

import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.DatagramPacket;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.client.gui.MyProps;

public final class Client {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());

    public void connect() throws InterruptedException {
        MyProps p = new MyProps();
        String host = p.getHost();
        int port = p.getServerPort();
        pingPongDatagram(host, port);
    }

    public void pingPongDatagram(String host, int port) throws InterruptedException {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
                    .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true)
                    .handler(new DatagramClientHandler());
            Channel ch = b.bind(0).sync().channel();
            ch.writeAndFlush(new DatagramPacket(
                    Unpooled.copiedBuffer("QOTM?", CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                    new InetSocketAddress(host, port))).sync();
            log.info("wrote packet");
            if (!ch.closeFuture().await(5000)) {
                log.warning("server timed out");
            }
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

handler:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.netty;

import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import io.netty.channel.socket.DatagramPacket;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DatagramClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DatagramClientHandler.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket msg) throws Exception {
        String response = msg.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
        log.info(response);
        DatagramPacket foo = new DatagramPacket(
                Unpooled.copiedBuffer("QOTM?", CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 4454));
        ctx.writeAndFlush(foo);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        log.severe(cause.toString());
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

I omitted the server code, it's almost exactly as in the [Ghandi quote example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/qotm).

What changes do I need to make to the **client** so that the **handler** can use `Foo` instead of `DatagramPacket`?

Answer (score 0):

All I can say with certainty is that this client:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.netty;

import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.DatagramPacket;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.client.gui.MyProps;
import net.bounceme.dur.client.jdbc.Title;

public final class Client {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());

    public void connect() throws InterruptedException {
        MyProps p = new MyProps();
        String host = p.getHost();
        int port = p.getServerPort();
        pingPongDatagram(host, port);
    }

    public void pingPongDatagram(String host, int port) throws InterruptedException {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
                    .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true)
                    .handler(new TitleClientHandler());
            Channel ch = b.bind(0).sync().channel();
            ch.writeAndFlush(new DatagramPacket(
                    Unpooled.copiedBuffer("QOTM?", CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                    new InetSocketAddress(host, port))).sync();
            ch.writeAndFlush(new Title());
            log.info("wrote packets");
            if (!ch.closeFuture().await(5000)) {
                log.warning("server timed out");
            }
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

and handler:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.netty;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.client.jdbc.Title;

public class TitleClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Title> {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TitleClientHandler.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        log.severe(cause.toString());
        ctx.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext chc, Title title) throws Exception {
        log.info(title.toString());
    }
}
```

don't, seemingly, communicate at all with the server -- even when the server has been modified accordingly.